# Blur event triggered when child gets focus

Tags: javascript, html, focus, dom-events, blur

I need to perform some action when and item loses its focus.

Basically I have something like this:

```
<div tabindex="1">
    <h1>title 1</h1>
</div>

<div tabindex="2">
    <h1>title 2</h1>

    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('div').blur((e) => { console.log('blur');});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/g6f1t0v1/1/)

Now, when you switch between `div`s it works like a charm, but when the second `div` has focus, and you click the child-textarea a `blur` event is triggered. This is not what I want, because we're still inside the same div. How can I fix this such that only a blur event is triggered when the click is outside the div ?

Answer (score 1):

a element has been focus then the last element focused will trigger event 'blur'.
You may have to design a hack for it...something like:

```
$('div').blur((e) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(!$('textarea').is(':focus')){
            console.log('blur');
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

setTimeout is important because blur event  being trigged in the first then focus event.

Comment: I've copied you code in the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g6f1t0v1/5/) but I don't  see a blur event when te textarea has focus and then you click outside its container div